# New Big Sur upgrade. . . downgrade for click drag?

Tags: trackpad, big-sur

When I try to move a window on my MacBook Air (press down with thumb on trackpad and use forefinger to move cursor & whatever object I grabbed) it takes 2 to 5 TIMES(!) for the cursor to actually take hold of the window and move it.  It appears there is NO correlation to exactly where on the upper pane margin I grab.  For weeks now I can't figure out where the "sweet spot" is!   It used to be you could place the cursor just about anywhere up there and it grabbed and moved. This is REALLY frustrating.

Wishing I had not upgraded because there is no apparent increase in the OS operation capability that I notice at all.

MacBook Air(mid-2013)

Comment: What is your question here? How to downgrade to Catalina, how to analyze and solve the window movement problem, something else? As for diagnosis, have you tried with an external mouse instead of the trackpad?

Comment: So this only occurred after upgrading to BigSur? Can you revert to Catalina/previous system with a backup? Does it happen in safe mode or after SMC or NVRAM/PRAM reset? Check the startup options here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: YES, it still happens with a magic mouse, same way.  Apparently I failed to make my concern obvious enough:   The legacy performance of Mac OS when moving windows appears to have changed with Big Sur upgrade.  Problem appears ONLY when attempting to click drag-- move a window on the TOP of the pane.   I will NOT be downgrading to keep performance as it was.  Question: Have others had this problem?   Question: Am I alone in the universe here?!  Could this be related to the revamped window graphics and structure in Big Sur vs Catalina.

Comment: OK, It is now June11, 2021 and it still happens using OS 11.2.3. I was on Apple Forum and found others with same OS level with a MacBook Air are NOT seeing this.   It generally takes me 3 times to move a window when cursor is near the top bar.   I found it works almost always however if I stay away from the various icons(eg home button on Safari; works best below the line of icons but not UNDER any of them. Safe mode suggestions above did not work. I guess I am alone in this little universe.  No solution for me here or Apple forum.

Comment: Does it still happen with 11.6?

Comment: I gave up.  Bought a NEW MacBook Air-- no problem!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to a problem in a beta version of macOS which has been resolved.

Comment: sure. Close it. Basically Apple updated the OS and kept doing so with sub-updates till they happened to fix what they messed up.  My solution was to buy a new Mac before they "found" it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally too frustrated to wait further I relented and called Apple.  Apparently this has been a problem in their beta issue of the OS-- 11.1.  Person I spoke with said he experienced it personally but since the latest *BETA FOR 11.2* has come out to developers it is gone.   I just need to wait till Apple bumps out their 11.2 OS version.

Comment: You can mark your own response as an answer